# Exception when I use InvokeScriptAsync in webview

Tags: javascript, webview, uwp

I have WebView in a UWP application that loads webpage, and I have InvokeScriptAsync Method that calls JS function:

```
InvokeScriptAsync("myFunction", new List<string>());
```

This code, fires *myFunction* correctly, and the return is correct.

```
function myFunction(){
    ...
    return true;    
}
```

But, when I have strange bug... when I set breakpoint in this call, the app blink and latter stops working correctly, but if I remove this breakpoint, the application works fine.

In another side, when I debug JavaScript with Script option in debug settings, the .NET application  Works correctly and apparently JavaScript too, but when *myFunction* return a value, blink again and app stops working.

I'ts posible that debug application influences the behavior of the application? Any idea to find the bug?

Thanks

Comment: I made a demo, but can't reproduce your problem. When my debug option is "Managed" The debug point of JS won't be triggered. The debug point of C# can be triggered. And when set the Debug setting to Script. JS debug point triggered correctly, C# break point not triggered.

Comment: Yes... I can't set breakpoint in C# code and Javascript code at the same time..

Answer (score 0):

> I can't set breakpoint in C# code and Javascript code at the same time

It is not a supported feature to debug managed codes(C#) and javascript in one Visual Studio Instance. Please see [Support Javascript/Managed mixed mode debugging](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4168526-support-javascript-managed-mixed-mode-debugging).